# Conflict between class and static library

Tags: iphone, conflict, reachability, layar

I'm using Layar Player in my app.
It provides a static library to include in your project.
After installing and trying to compile, I got this error:

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability in
>   //LayarPlayer/Debug/liblayarplayer.a(Reachability.o) and
>   //MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Reachability.o
>   for architecture armv7

I'm using Reachability in my app to check network status, but it seems like it's already included in the library.
I've tried removing every **#import Reachability** in my code, but obviously I get "undeclared function" errors.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Perhaps remove Reachability from your project and use `-ObjC` `-all_load` linker flags for your project?

Comment: This is what documentation suggests to do, but removing Reachability I get "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I excluded all conflicting .m files from the target and everything is fine now.
Headers files must not be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete the references from the project. That means don't delete the `#import Reachability` but search for `Reachability.m` and `Reachability.h` in your project files and delete them so you only have one of each in your project.

Comment: I get "no such file or directory".

Comment: You still have at least one `Reachability.m` and `Reachability.h` file in your project right?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same problem by

1. check your project remove duplicate Reachability file;
2. replacing old version of Reachability(I'm currently using version 2.2);
3. put the -ObjC -all_load linker flags on.

Hope it may help.