# linking error in CanvasPop API ios

Tags: ios, xcode, api

I am integarting canvaspop in my application.When I am integrating it in sample application it is working fine.But when I am using it in my app  with other 3rd pary framework like GPUimage,IKImagePicker,xpload and other more.I am getting these errors while linking framework to my app.

```
Ld /Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageEditorPro.app/ImageEditorPro normal i386
cd "/Volumes/DATA/Chakshu/clientProjects/Kamil/Editlab Testing/EditLab"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -LVendors/IAPPVerification -LVendors/TestFlight -LVendors/Canvas -F/Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -FVendors/IKImagePickerController/Vendors/FacebookSDK -FImageEditorPro -FVendors/GooglePlus -F/Volumes/DATA/Chakshu/clientProjects/Kamil/Editlab\ Testing/EditLab/IddictionSDK.embeddedframework -F/Volumes/DATA/Chakshu/clientProjects/Kamil/Editlab\ Testing/EditLab/IddictionSDK.embeddedframework/XplodeSDK.embeddedframework -F/Volumes/DATA/Chakshu/clientProjects/Kamil/Editlab\ Testing/EditLab/XplodeSDK.embeddedframework -FVendors/Canvas -F/Volumes/DATA/Chakshu/clientProjects/Kamil/Editlab\ Testing/EditLab/Vendors/Canvas -filelist /Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Intermediates/ImageEditorPro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageEditorPro.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageEditorPro.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CFNetwork -framework Accelerate -lz -lObjectiveFlickr -framework PopUpLib /Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTMTumblrSDK.a -framework CoreMotion -framework MediaPlayer -framework StoreKit -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework FacebookSDK -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MapKit -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework OpenGLES -framework AVFoundation /Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGPUImage.a -framework AdSupport -lsqlite3 -framework Social -framework Accounts -framework AssetsLibrary -lbeeblex -framework ImageIO -framework QuartzCore /Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libIKImagePickerController.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -lTestFlight -framework XplodeSDK -framework Foundation -framework GooglePlus -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Intermediates/ImageEditorPro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageEditorPro.build/Objects-normal/i386/ImageEditorPro_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageEditorPro.app/ImageEditorPro

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability in:
/Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Intermediates/ImageEditorPro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageEditorPro.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
Vendors/Canvas/PopUpLib.framework/PopUpLib(libPopUpLib.a-i386-master.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Reachability in:
/Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Intermediates/ImageEditorPro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageEditorPro.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
Vendors/Canvas/PopUpLib.framework/PopUpLib(libPopUpLib.a-i386-master.o)

duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:
/Users/mandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageEditorPro-bkvuyjzwftcotmgjlrocdiyaqkqu/Build/Intermediates/ImageEditorPro.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageEditorPro.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
Vendors/Canvas/PopUpLib.framework/PopUpLib(libPopUpLib.a-i386-master.o)

ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think there are some setting in the build setting which have to change to successfully link this framework to app.
Thanks

Comment: Hey there, did you follow the video showcased here: https://developers.canvaspop.com/documentation/integration-mobile you may have forgotten a step

Comment: yes.I have seen the video.I integrated it in sample code.

Comment: The library may be conflicting with other third party frameworks. What libraries are you using other than ImageEditorPro?

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at this question and solution:

[Conflict between class and static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725008/conflict-between-class-and-static-library)

It explains how the .m files are possibly conflicting with each other.

Try out this solution and comment on the outcome.